# Disable foreign key link in django admin

Tags: django, admin

I've got a Django admin site with two models : Client and User (Users are member of a Company working with Clients).
Each client has a user referent, so Client has a field 'sales_contact' which is a Foreign Key to User.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField()
    sales_contact = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={'role':2}
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name}, {self.last_name}"
```

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['last_name', 'sales_contact']
```

A user only having 'view client permission' can however click on the name of the 'sales_contact' (corresponding to a link to the user change view) and will be directed to the 403 Forbidden page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Vqm.png)

According to me, it would be preferably to disable this link when user has no change permission.

I tried to use

```
list_display_links
```

but it only works with list view, not detailed views.

How to do this, please ?

Livior

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'readonly_fields' to make this amendment in your code

In admin.py do the following according to your code:

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['sales_contact']

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

This will display the sales_contact field as a read-only field in the Django admin, and the user will not be able to edit the value of the field.

Comment: Unfortunately, use of `readonly_fields` doesn't solve my problem. The 'sales_contact' field remains clickable and leads to a 403 Forbidden page.

Answer (score 0):

I found !
I had to create a new field, `sales_contact_no_link` which is a function returning `sales_contact` with an HTML form without link :

```
@admin.display
def sales_contact_no_link(self, obj):
    return format_html("{}", obj.sales_contact)
```

Then, I use `get_fields` to get the required fields dependant of the user status :

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ['last_name', 'sales_contact']
        else:
            return ['last_name', 'sales_contact_no_link']

    @admin.display
    def sales_contact_no_link(self, obj):
        return format_html("{}", obj.sales_contact)
```

And so it works.

Answer (score 0):

set exclude on the admin model

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['last_name']
    exclude = ['sales_contact']
```